# How to get the dynamic package from which a TPersistentClass comes from?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, runtime-packages

My application is built using [runtime packages](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178) and loads them by using the [`LoadPackage`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/dynamicallyloadingpackages_xml.html) function.
Then it uses the [`GetClass`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_GetClass.html) function to obtain class types.

```
var
  MyClass : TPersistentClass;
begin
  if(LoadPackage('.\PackageA.bpl') = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error loading PackageA.bpl');
  if(LoadPackage('.\PackageB.bpl') = 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error loading PackageB.bpl');

  MyClass := GetClass('TMyClass');
end;
```

Is there any way to get the name of the package from which `MyClass` comes from?

Comment: On modern Delphi versions TPresistentClass has `UnitName` method available, but I'm afraid that in older versions you need to descend your classes from TObject at least to have Access to such method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the RTL's [`FindClassHInstance()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.FindClassHInstance) function to get the handle of the loaded package that owns the class type that [`GetClass()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.GetClass) returns.  This will be the same handle that [`LoadPackage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.LoadPackage) returns.

You can either track the loaded package handles yourself, or you can pass the handle to the Win32 API [`GetModuleFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) function to query the handle for its package's path and filename.